# Flex Datagrid - how to obtain item for mouse x/y coordinates?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, datagrid

my mission is to select an item in a DataGrid instance with nothing but the coordinates on screen.

We are implementing right-click functionality in our Flash application, with the goal of being able to right-click a DG row, which would select that row plus show a popup window containing some context commands.

I have managed to get the right click event into my Flex app with the help of [this site](http://www.uza.lt/blog/2007/08/solved-right-click-in-as3/).

Further progress so far has been to obtain the DataGrid instance via

```
var objects : Array = this.getObjectsUnderPoint(new Point(this.mouseX, this.mouseY));
```

and then to investige each of the array's items, for one of those 'parent.parentList' refers to the DataGrid instance.

Now I am stuck -- I couldn't find any point-to-item converter function or anything. Any comments about my approach so far very welcome, too!

Thanks!

PS: Using the standard Flash ContextMenu is, unfortunately, **not** an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
* Let mx and my be the mouse coordinates 
* (relative to the stage, not relative to the clicked object)
* */

var len:Number = dg.dataProvider.length;
var i:Number;
var p1:Point;
var p2:Point;
var renderer:DisplayObject;
for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
  renderer = DisplayObject(dg.indexToItemRenderer(i));
  if(!renderer)//item is not displayed (scroll to view it)
    continue;
  p1 = new Point(renderer.x, renderer.y);
  p2 = new Point(renderer.width, renderer.height);
  p1 = renderer.parent.localToGlobal(p1);
  p2 = renderer.localToGlobal(p2);
  if(mx >= p1.x && mx <= p2.x && my >= p1.y && my <= p2.y)
  {
    trace("You clicked on " + dg.dataProvider.getItemAt(i));
    break;
  }
}
```

---

You can attach the [ContextMenu](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/ui/ContextMenu.html) to the DataGrid's `itemRenderer` instead - that way you can get the right-clicked item from the event's `currentTarget` property. As simple as it can get.

Comment: No, unfortunately its not. Using the standard Flex ContextMenu is not an option, so back to square one: "my mission is to select an item in a DataGrid instance with nothing but the coordinates on screen."

Comment: if you are able to get datagrid using the items-under-point function, you should be able to get the item renderer too.

Comment: Great, works like a charm! I have added an answer with the complete code, see below. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [itemRollOver](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#event:itemRollOver) event (and the related itemRollOut) to keep track of the most recent item that the mouse was over. Just save the item in a variable. When you display the context menu, you can use the saved item directly rather than trying to find it based on the (x,y) coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete AS3 code for the Flash side of things. Note that you also need Javascript in your embedding HTML to make it work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="horizontal" 
 minWidth="1024" minHeight="768"
 creationComplete="onAppCreationComplete()"
 click="onRightClick()"
>
 <mx:DataGrid
  id="dgTest"
  dataProvider="{['aaa','bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb']}"
  >
  <mx:columns>
   <mx:DataGridColumn />
  </mx:columns>
 </mx:DataGrid>

 <mx:Script>
 <![CDATA[
  import mx.binding.utils.BindingUtils;
  import mx.controls.Alert;
  import mx.controls.Menu;
  import mx.effects.Fade;
  import mx.events.MenuEvent;

  [Bindable]
  public var customContextMenuItem : Object;

  public var customContextMenu : Menu;


  protected function onAppCreationComplete () : void
  {
   ExternalInterface.addCallback("rightClick", onRightClick);
   this.customContextMenu = this.createCustomContextMenu();
  }


  protected function onRightClick () : void
  {
   // find datagrid at mouse click coords
   var dg : DataGrid = this.getDataGridFromObjectsUnderPoint(this.mouseX, this.mouseY);
   if (dg) {
    // if any, find clicked item
    this.customContextMenuItem = this.findClickedItem(this.mouseX, this.mouseY, dg);
    if (this.customContextMenuItem) {
     // right clicking an item with the menu already showing does not show a new menu
     // unless the previous one is hidden first
     this.customContextMenu.hide();
     this.customContextMenu.show(this.mouseX+3, this.mouseY+2);
    }
   }
  }


  protected function getDataGridFromObjectsUnderPoint (x:Number, y:Number) : DataGrid
  {
   var objectsHere : Array = this.getObjectsUnderPoint(new Point(this.mouseX, this.mouseY));
   for each (var dispObj:DisplayObject in objectsHere) {
    while (dispObj) {
     if (dispObj is DataGrid)
      return dispObj as DataGrid;
     dispObj = dispObj.parent;
    }
   }
   return null;
  }


  /**
   * Returns a dataProvider item that displays at the given coords for the given dataGrid.
   * Code provided by Stackoverflow user http://stackoverflow.com/users/165297/amarghosh,
   * thanks a lot!
   */
  protected function findClickedItem (x:Number, y:Number, dg:DataGrid) : Object
  {
   var p1 : Point;
   var p2 : Point;
   var renderer : DisplayObject;

   for(var i:int=0; i<dg.dataProvider.length; i++) {
    renderer = DisplayObject(dg.indexToItemRenderer(i));
    if (!renderer) //item is not displayed (scroll to view it)
     continue;
    p1 = new Point(renderer.x, renderer.y);
    p2 = new Point(renderer.width, renderer.height);
    p1 = renderer.parent.localToGlobal(p1);
    p2 = renderer.localToGlobal(p2);
    if(x >= p1.x && x <= p2.x && y >= p1.y && y <= p2.y)
     return dg.dataProvider.getItemAt(i);
   }   
   return null;
  }


  protected function createCustomContextMenu () : Menu
  {
   // create a dynamic-object as our first menu item entry, and use data binding
   // to dynamically populate the 'title' value whenever our right-clicked item 
   // has changed
   var menuItem : Object = new Object();
   menuItem.title = "default";
   BindingUtils.bindSetter(function (item:Object) : void {
    trace(item);
    menuItem.title = "Edit '" + item + "'";
   }, this, ["customContextMenuItem"]);
   var dataProvider : Array = [ menuItem, {title:"Exit"} ];

   // create a nicely styled menu that looks very different to the standard Flash menu
   var menu : Menu = Menu.createMenu(this, dataProvider, false);
   menu.setStyle("fontWeight", "bold");
   menu.setStyle("backgroundColor", 0x000000);  // standard back/foreground
   menu.setStyle("color", 0xf0f0f0);
   menu.setStyle("rollOverColor", 0x444444);   // mouse hover back/foreground
   menu.setStyle("textRollOverColor", 0xffffff);
   menu.setStyle("selectionColor", 0x444444);  // mouse click back/foreground
   menu.setStyle("textSelectedColor", 0xe18c31);
   menu.setStyle("openDuration", 0);
   menu.labelField = "title";

   // we want to react to clicks in the menu
   menu.addEventListener(MenuEvent.ITEM_CLICK, function (event:MenuEvent) : void {
    Alert.show("Menu item clicked - clicked item title '" + event.item.title + "'");
   });

   // done
   return menu;
  }
 ]]>
 </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

`dg` is the `dataGrid`.
The coordinate of the top of the row in dg's contents system (i.e. from the header's bottom) is:

```
var topOfRow:int = ( int(dg.mouseY / dg.rowHeight) -1 ) * dg.rowHeight;
```

You can now adjust to other coordinate systems:
For example to dg's system:

```
topOfRow += dh.headerHeight;
```

Or use `localToGlobal()` or whatever.